Ramification divisor defined by intersection on Grassmannian bundle
Recently, I learn ramification covering between complex manifolds in my own research. I am studying how to describe ramification divisors of a ramification covering. I know one method is to define ramification divisors as zero locus (counted with multiplicity) of Jacobian determiant. When we have an ambient manifold, I am wondering whether we can use intersection theory of analytic varieties (William Fulton's book) on Grassmannian manifolds to describe ramification divisors. More precisely, I can give a concrete question as follows:
Consider a $k$-dimensional complex submanifold $\Gamma$ of $\mathbb{B} = B_{k}(0,3)\times B_{l}(0,4)$, which is contained in $B_{k}(0,3)\times B_{l}(0,1)$. Here, $B_{k}(0,3)$  means the $k$-dimensional complex open ball at origin of radius 3. Similarly for $B_{l}(0,4)$. We require $ \Gamma \subset B_{k}(0,3)\times B_{l}(0,1)$ because we just want the canonical projection map $\pi|_{\Gamma} : \Gamma \to B_{k}(0,3)$ is a ramified covering map. Let $J$ denote its ramification divisor on $\Gamma$, determined by the Jacobian determinant of $\pi$, which is a divisor with positive interger coefficients.
Now, I want to say how I understand it from intersection of varieties on the Grassmannian bundle of $\mathbb{B}$.
Let the Grassmannian manifold $\mathbb{G}(k+l,l)$ denote all $l$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{k+l}$. Define $Gr(\mathbb{B},l):=\mathbb{B}\times\mathbb{G}(k+l,l)$, which can be understood as the set of $ (z,[v])$ where $z$ is a point in $\mathbb{B}$ and $[v]$ is the direction of $l$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{B}$ at $z$. So, we have ${\rm dim}\,\mathbb{G}(k+l,l)= kl$ and ${\rm dim}\, Gr(\mathbb{B},l)=k+l+kl$.
Denote by $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ be set of points $(z,[v])\in Gr(\mathbb{B},l)$ such that $z\in \Gamma$ and $v$ is not transverse to the tangent space of $\Gamma$ at $z$. So, $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ is an analytic subset of $Gr(\mathbb{B},l)$ of pure dimension $k+kl-1$. Indeed, it is not difficult to see that the restriction of $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ to a fiber $\{ z\}\times \mathbb{G}(k+l,l)$ is a hypersurface (possibly with singularities) of this fiber.
The canonical projection map $\pi: B_{k}(0,3) \times B_{l}(0,4) \to B_{k}(0,3)$ can be understood as do projection along an element $v_0\in \mathbb{G}(k+l,l) $. Intuitively, it should be "vertical" direction. Now, we consider the intersection of $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ with $ \mathbb{B} \times \{ v_0\}$ in $Gr(\mathbb{B},l)$. Both $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ and $ \mathbb{B} \times \{ v_0\}$ are analytic varieties (irreducible, reduced analytic sets) of $Gr(\mathbb{B},l)$. Moreover. the intersection of these two is proper, i.e. ${\rm codim}\, \widetilde{\Gamma}\cap (\mathbb{B} \times \{ v_0\})={\rm codim}\, \widetilde{\Gamma}+{\rm codim}\, (\mathbb{B} \times \{ v_0\} )$ in $ Gr(\mathbb{B},l)$. I learn from Wiki that, in intersection theory, we can discuss about its intersection number (Serre's Tor formula) of its irreducible component.
When we consider projection image of $\widetilde{\Gamma}\cap (\mathbb{B} \times \{ v_0\}) $ to $\Gamma$, we can also get a interger coefficients divisor $J'$ defined by Serre's Tor formula. It is easy to realize the support of $J$ and $J'$ are the same analytic sets. However, I don't know whether they have the same multiplicity. I try some examples when $k=1$ and $l=1$ (the plane curve cases), and I feel $J$ and $J'$ should be same as divisors on $\Gamma$. However, I don't know how to show it in higher dimension because I'm not familiar with Serre's Tor formula. Could anyone give me some references?
